# paste content from clipboard to text file in ex mode?

Tags: vim, paste

In normal mode `"+p` can paste content in `+` regiter to text file ,`+p` can't paste content from clipboard  to text file in ex mode,how can?

```
:reg +
--- Registers ---
"+   smartphone
```

There is a word `smartphone` in my register `+`.
The original text contain two lines,cursor is at the beginning of the third line.

```
line1
line2
```

In normal mode `"+p` will add a line containning word `smartphone` ,it is like the below:

```
line1
line2
smartphone
```

Now i move cursor to the beginning of the fourth line,turn into ex mode(type shift and :),go on to type what command and click enter can add one more `smartphone`?

```
line1
line2
smartphone
smartphone
```

Comment: Please clarify question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using 'put' command

```
:put +
```

Comment: Damn, this doesn't work over SSH.